# Jackson Java 8 LocalDateTime serialization with nanos

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, jodatime

Currently, I'm trying to migrate a project form joda time to java8 time api.

After the replacing joda components with java8 components, I have serialization problems. Of course, I added dependencies and register new `JavaTimeModule()` module. 
But when I try to serialize

```
LocalDateTime.of(1988, 11, 10, 7, 31, 32, 0)
```

I receive an array `[1988,11,10,7,31,32]` but `[1988,11,10,7,31,32,**0**]` is expected (with nanos).

So, the question is: **is it possible to serialize time with nanos, even if it's 0**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having a look at the jackson `LocalDateTimeSerializer` code, the seconds and the nanos are explicitly ignored when their values are `0`

```
private final void _serializeAsArrayContents(LocalDateTime value, JsonGenerator g, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
    g.writeNumber(value.getYear());
    g.writeNumber(value.getMonthValue());
    g.writeNumber(value.getDayOfMonth());
    g.writeNumber(value.getHour());
    g.writeNumber(value.getMinute());
    int secs = value.getSecond();
    int nanos = value.getNano();
    if (secs > 0 || nanos > 0) {
        g.writeNumber(secs);
        if (nanos > 0) {
            if (this.useNanoseconds(provider)) {
                g.writeNumber(nanos);
            } else {
                g.writeNumber(value.get(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In order to achieve the desired result you have to create a custom serializer and register its module after the `JavaTimeModule`

```
public class LocalDateTimeWithNanoSerializer extends StdSerializer<LocalDateTime> {

    public LocalDateTimeWithNanoSerializer() {
        super(LocalDateTime.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(LocalDateTime value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartArray();
        gen.writeNumber(value.getYear());
        gen.writeNumber(value.getMonthValue());
        gen.writeNumber(value.getDayOfMonth());
        gen.writeNumber(value.getHour());
        gen.writeNumber(value.getMinute());
        gen.writeNumber(value.getSecond());
        gen.writeNumber(value.getNano());
        gen.writeEndArray();
    }
}
```

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleModule myModule = new SimpleModule();
        myModule.addSerializer(new LocalDateTimeWithNanoSerializer());
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
              .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
              .registerModule(myModule)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Hope it works. But it's not relevant for me anymore )